# VisualStudio2005 very slow in debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have 1GB ram in my pc. 
In my solution totally 48 projects are there. 
But I am debugging only one project.
Each project is depending on other one.
While debugging the project why visual studio is taking much memory usage. Also system is getting hanged.

Can any one please let me know if you have any suggestion to solve this debugging issue.

Comment: 1GB of RAM is not much for VS solution with 48 projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS is just not very good at large projects/solutions, and MS is constantly claiming to be improving this (though forward progress on VS is always terribly hard to detect...)

My suggestions would be:

- 1GB is not enough RAM for the size of project you're working with
- VS2008 might well be better than VS2005
- Check that you're not trying to download symbols into the debugger
- Don't use the debugger (F5) if you just want to run the app - use Ctrl-F5

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting many options. I would like to know how to check the symbols are downloading or not into the debugger?
Thanks,
Haranadh

Comment: Have a look at the Debug->Symbols page in the VS options.  And/or run Fiddler while you start debugging and see if there's a huge amount of web activity

Comment: Thank you so much I forgot that I had symbols defined and it was pulling them down over a slow vpn you saved my day!!

Answer (score 0):

I do recall an issue where breakpoints would double up every time you did... something I can't remember.

Check if you have 1000s of breakpoints set (all for the same lines).

Comment: I don't have break points more than 5. But still it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off Inline complete (in the options)? This can sometimes cause this type of problem?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. Could you please let me know, which option I need to change. I could not get "inline complete" option.
Thanks
Haranadh

Answer (score 0):

Just to get this out in the open -- is it possible to reduce the complexity of your solution?  Do you really need 48 projects in there?  How big is the project that you're working on in total?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this and fixed it by stopping my Virus Scanner from scanning the Directories  Visual Studio uses as the Virus Scanner and IDE/Design Time compiler were locking each other for several seconds at a time sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Mine was taking a full 20 seconds to start debugging. I deleted all breakpoints and that fixed it. :)